# APEX Column value to change based on LOV in IG

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

[Screenshot of my settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrAYI.png)  On Interactive Grid - I have column-a "TaskID" and other column-b is "Predecessors", which is LOV of “TaskID” column. Each TaskID has a start date in Column-C. When I change the column-b value, the column-C date should change. I mean it should look for the TaskID column and return the corresponding date.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. May be a dynamic action or SQL query.. I don’t know

Column a (TaskID), Column b (Predecessors), Column c (StartDate)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using a dynamic action will be the easiest way to do this.

Create an on change dynamic action on your predecessors column:
[image: Screenshot]

Then create a Set Value Action using the corresponding SQL query:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I tried this no luck, it is not returning the startdate value.

Comment: Make sure that you are also setting the "Items to Submit" attribute to your predecessors column name

Comment: Thanks for your support, still no go. I have attached the screenshot of my settings to my original post.

Comment: Do you have any other inputs based on the screen shot i shared? Thanks

Comment: Will you be able to help with the screenshot I shared. Not sure why its not working.

Comment: I just replicated a similar test case on my APEX 5.1.4 test instance, I can set the date column correctly.

It might be a query or data issue. I would suggest you have a look at the AJAX call's Payload under the DevTools Network tab. You should be able to see what value gets submitted when the predecessors column changes. With that value you should be able to run the DA's query and compare. You can also have a look the AJAX's reponse.